# Netty IO write to server from outside the class

Tags: java, class, client, netty, server

I want to make a simple Netty Server and I have the basic Server/Client code, but I have a problem. How do I write to the server from outside the Client Main class?

Here´s the code:

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public final class ChatClient {

    static final String HOST = System.getProperty("host", "127.0.0.1");
    static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", "8992"));

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group)
             .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
             .handler(new ChatClientInitializer());

            Channel ch = b.connect(HOST, PORT).sync().channel();

            ChannelFuture lastWriteFuture = null;
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            for (;;) {
                String line = in.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                }
                // WRITE TO SERVER, HOW DO I CALL THIS OUTSIDE FROM THIS CLASS TO WRITE TO THE SERVER?
                lastWriteFuture = ch.writeAndFlush(line + "\r\n");
            }

            if (lastWriteFuture != null) {
                lastWriteFuture.sync();
            }
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

As noted in the comments, I want to send messages to the Server from outside this class. How can I do that?

Best Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can just make the Channel accessible from the outside by expose it via a getter and use it. Channel is thread safe and so can be used from any thread.

Comment: Can you please post an example how I would do that? I know what getters and setters are but I really can't immagine how to do that :( Thank you